# How to prevent newline characters in the Wildfly logs?

Tags: logging, wildfly

I need to prevent newline characters in the Wildfly logs.
New line characters cause the “Improper Output Neutralization for Logs” flaw (http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/117.html ).
I was able to do it in log4j2 using the following pattern:

```
%replace{%msg}{[\r\n]+}{ }%n
```

I cannot find the replace in the Wildfly logs configuration:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration

Comment: Sorry - no answer for you but I'm curious - how would a hacker know what things are logged and not logged in an application?   You can use log4j in your web application if you're concerned about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [filter expresions](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-FilterExpressions), this is the `filter-spec` attribute on loggers and handlers. It's best to put them on a handler.

Something like the following CLI command should work:

```
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:write-attribute(name=filter-spec, value="substituteAll(\"[\r\n]+\", \"\")")
```

One thing to note however is this only works on the message itself. If there is a stack trace associated with the message it will not be processed by the filter.